# Quotation Marks do not work in latex with specific document class

Tags: pdftex, quotation

I tried all to make the quotation marks work but still failed! 
I tried ``` ``word'' ``` , I also tried `csquotes` but still it is not working and instead of proper quotation marks the result is `"word"`.

It works when I use the `article` document class or other popular document classes. 
But when I am working with the document class file for writing thesis( http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis), quotation marks do not work.

Is it something related to quotation marks in cls files that I have to add to the cls file I am using or problem is something else?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Since we have no idea what your university is or what that class is we will be unable to help you. Can you edit your question to give a link to the document class and add a minimal document using the class that shows the problem?

Comment: I just checked it is the same template as Masters/Doctoral Thesis on latextemplates website: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis
When I try to use quotation marks in this template it does not work

Comment: This is simply due to the font being used. The quotation marks are not in fact identical. See [Palatino displays wrong opening quotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/12096/2693)

Comment: Oh I see you are right! When I look closely, now I can see That's still a quotation mark but with different font!