# How to add LaTeX style quotation marks to the Hunspell spell checker?

Tags: punctuation, spelling

Quotation marks in LaTeX have to be added with ``` `` ``` and `''`, but this results in the word being marked as misspelled in Texmaker, which uses Hunspell files (`.dic` and `.aff`). I tried adding ``` `` ``` and `''` to the `.dic` file, but this resulted in all words marked as incorrect. How do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't yet possible. I think it is time to [report](https://code.google.com/p/texmaker/issues/list) the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are many [ways to add quotation marks](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-quotation-mark-glyphs). In my opinion the nicest solution is the [csquotes](http://ctan.org/pkg/csquotes) package. The csquotes package basically provides the `\enquote{}` command that will give you correct quotes in (nearly) all cases and languages. Plus, the Texmaker spell check works with it, solving your issue as a side effect.