# The Quotation Mark character in TeXworks editor has vanished

Tags: texworks

Now, my version of TeXworks is 0.4.5r.1280 and I can't have the `"` character on the keyboard.

I have ``` `` ```  or `''` instead. Why?

And It's the same with `Alt+034`. I'm very disappointed with that.

Comment: Check Format -> Smart Quotes: do you have this turned on? If so, TeXworks will deliberately turn `"` into `\`\`` or `''` (depending on the settings).

Comment: For future reference: The reason TeXworks does this is because (all?) the various flavors of TeX use `\`\`` for a opening double quotation mark and `''` for a closing double quotation mark. TeXworks is trying to be helpful by "autocorrecting" you on the fly. (See, for example, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-quotation-mark-glyphs?lq=1.)

Answer (score 17):

TeXworks has a 'Smart Quotes' mode that deliberately changes `"` to either ``` `` ``` or `''` using some context-dependent 'cleverness'. This is available as `"` is very rarely needed in a typesetting context. However, the setting is easy enough to turn off.

For a single file, you can go to Format -> Smart Quotes and choose None: this turns off the auto-conversion for the current file. To turn it off generally, go to Preferences (Edit menu on Windows/Linux, TeXworks menu on the Mac) and select 'None' under 'Smart Quotes' on the 'Edit' tab.

Comment: In text mode we are supposed to use two single quotes indeed --but-- in math mode it is supposed to be a double quote. So TeXworks' feature ought to be completed by a quick way of recovering the double quote symbol (faster than going into the menu back and forth all the time).

Comment: You can also type Ctrl-z (undo) after inserting the double quote in order to undo the automatic translation.