# TeXWorks keeps replacing " with '' (i.e. 1 " with 2 ') and that's bad

Tags: texworks

I wish to properly accent Hölder's name in LaTeX by using `\"{o}`, but TeXWorks keeps replacing my double quote with a single quote. My hacky workaround to this is to copy the `"` unicode character from a browser and directly paste it into TeXWorks, but I would like a more permanent solution. Is there a way to make TeXWorks stop doing this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which platform -- Windows? MacOS? something else? -- your copy of TeXworks runs on.

Comment: Why don't you simply type Hölder?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210145/the-quotation-mark-character-in-texworks-editor-has-vanished/210148#210148 perhaps

Comment: @JosephWright this worked, thanks!