# Does UTF8 add right-quote and left-quote recognition to LaTeX, XeTeX?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, punctuation, unicode

I've got a LaTeX novel writing project with lots of character quotations.  I use Focuswriter to create chapter text files (ASCII, UTF-8).  There is no LaTeX markup in the chapter files.  A LaTeX master file will include all the code, and have lots of `\include{chapter}` files, etc.

So, I need LaTeX to be able to understand that right and left quotes are not special characters, and I don't want to have to code them into the chapter files.  Does UTF-8 add this automatically within LaTeX or XeTeX?  Or, is there a package that understand those for pdfTeX or XeTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, LaTeX will parse the left and right quotation marks correctly if you tell it to parse the input with UTF-8 encoding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
‘Hello’
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can you edit the other question and post your code and image into the checkmarked answer of 
http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-quotation-mark-glyphs
so that if this question gets deleted, that the answer will be clear in the other question's answer?
http://i.stack.imgur.com/4KBpe.png

Comment: @user12711 Duplicate questions aren't deleted, so don't worry about it. I see no need to edit the original question's answer, because the code provided there is essentially the same as my code in this answer.