# Style of quotation marks

Tags: csquotes

This time I would like to ask you if you know how to change the style of signs on the left side and on the right side of a quotation. First quotation mark (that on the left) should be two commas at the bottom and the second (that on the right side) - two commas on the top on the right (schematically - bottom(,,)...top(,,)).

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-quotation-mark-glyphs.

Comment: In particular [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/240595/) to that question explains **csquotes** ability to adapt quotation marks to both nesting and linguistic context.

Comment: OK, but what if someone has to use quotes with a chosen style ({,,}{"} - something like that), without the environment \begin{quotation} \end{quotation}?

Comment: My answer below doesn't use the `quotation` environment and the answer I linked to doesn't depend on the `quotation` environment. The **csquotes** work there has nothing to do with that environment. It is just a result of the use of active quotation marks and **csquotes**. The answer I posted below doesn't use active marks, but only the macro `\enquote{}`. Normally, you use the style of marks appropriate to the language you are typesetting. It wouldn't make sense for me to choose, say, guillements if I'm typesetting English. You can specify a style if you need to, but usually `auto` is right.

Answer (score 14):

You can use **csquotes**:

```
\documentclass[spanish,french,ngerman,american,british]{article}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
  \enquote{UK English} \selectlanguage{american} \enquote{US English} \selectlanguage{spanish} \enquote{Spanish} \selectlanguage{french} \enquote{Français} \selectlanguage{ngerman} \enquote{Deutsche}
\end{document}
```

[image: language-variant quotation marks]

Note that I have no idea if these are correct except for the first two. I'm just going by the package claiming they are!

## EDIT

Since you are typesetting Polish, things are not quite so straightforward as **csquotes** doesn't know what the marks should look like. However, I believe that the style is the same as for Dutch. If so, then a simple alias allows us to get the correct style for Polish:

```
\documentclass[polish]{article}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteAlias{dutch}{polish}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
  \enquote{Polish}
\end{document}
```

[image: Polish (hopefully)]

Comment: Ha, ha, ha... funny situation :) So I'll tell you: Polish. I will check it.  If it doesn't work properly , I will add a comment, else I will add a comment "thank you" or something longer :D.

Comment: Polish isn't supported but we can add it. Which way should the commas point? Can you post an image of what it should look like? I know nothing about Polish!

Comment: In Polish quotation marks look like „[text]”

Comment: Please see edit. Is that right for Polish?

Comment: @cfr: For French, it is fine. For Polish, it's funny: I get the same result with `DeclareQuoteAlias{croatian}{polish}`.

Comment: @Bernard Good.... I'm glad to hear it. To be clear: it was not obvious to me which language was needed from the question because I do not know which languages use which typographical conventions, except in the very vaguest terms. So I just gave some examples.

Comment: @Paweł Excellent!

Comment: Yes, I see. In my opinion, excellent solution. I didn't know that quotation marks in Dutch are simply the same as these in Polish

Comment: @Paweł Me neither. I just looked up **csquotes** and tried the styles I hadn't used hoping one would look like what you'd described. Norwegian was half-right, but Dutch looked better. Interestingly, it has no aliases, so probably the package author doesn't know that Polish quotation marks are simply the same as those in Dutch!

Comment: Of course. But, on the other side, somebody can simply use Dutch to define Polish, as you did, so actually it is not needed.

Comment: @Paweł Yes, but plenty of other aliases are defined to correspond to **babel** and **polyglossia**.  Even e.g. `newzealand` is defined as an alias to `british`.

Comment: OK, you conquered me, I agree :).  And to be clear, I'm a patriot.

Comment: @Paweł Maybe I could get them to add `welsh` as well... ;).

Comment: Yes, of course. :)

Comment: But are Welsh quotation marks the same as in British English? Because Welsh language is a little bit another.

Comment: @Paweł Yes. We'd use the same kind of quotation marks. Punctuation is very, very similar, for all that the language is quite different. (No possessive apostrophes, though, but that's because we make possessives completely differently.)

Comment: Very interesting.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to use two commas at the beginning and two apostrophes at the end.

```
,,Polish''
```

Latex will convert it correctly to „Polish”