# My citations in Biblatex do not appear and a "ç" appear when not needed

Tags: biblatex, cross-referencing, citing, babel, spanish

The "C" appears as a "Ç", and my citations do not appear.

```
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
    %\usepackage{amssymb}

    \usepackage[
    style=alphabetic,
    bibencoding=utf8,
    sorting=ynt
    ]{biblatex}
    %\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
    \addbibresource{biblio.bib}

    \pagestyle{empty}
    \voffset-3cm

    \title{Resumen:\\Clasificaci\'on de  usando Redes Neuronales Convolucionales}
    \date{13 de Junio del 2017}
    \begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \thispagestyle{empty}

    Se realizar\'an diferentes analisis sobre cromatograf\'ias de suelo. Las "Cromatograf\'ias en Filtro Redondo de Pfeiffer"\cite{folla}. Este\cite{croma}.

    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography[env=bibliography]
    \end{document}
```

The `.bib` file is placed at the main document's directory, as well.

Comment: The Ç is because you use `"C` which is a short-hand command from the `babel` package. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-quotation-mark-glyphs) for how to produce proper quotations marks in the output. Please also provide the contents of your .bib file. Your can Insert the file in this document using the [filecontents](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) package.

Comment: You will need to run Biber. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864) as well as [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). If you have run Biber you should be able to find a `.blg` file. If you still have problems after running LaTeX -> Biber -> LaTeX -> LaTeX, please show us the `.blg` file.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use "dumb" quotation marks -- `"` -- to quote a word or passage in a TeX or LaTeX document. This gets you in trouble with `babel`'s setting of using `"` to initiate various typing shortcuts. Instead, either use "smart" quotation marks, viz.,

```
`` and ''
```

or load the `csquotes` package (with language option `spanish=spanish` or `spanish=mexican`, as appropriate) and write

```
\enquote{Cromatograf\'ias en Filtro Redondo de Pfeiffer}
```

in the body of the document.

About your citations not appearing: After running LaTeX, did you run `biber` followed by an additional LaTeX run?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}
%\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[
   style=alphabetic,
   bibencoding=utf8,
   sorting=ynt
   ]{biblatex}
%\defbibenvironment{bibliography}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}

\pagestyle{empty}
\voffset-3cm

\title{Resumen:\\Clasificaci\'on de  usando\\Redes Neuronales Convolucionales}
\date{13 de Junio del 2017}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}

Se realizar\'an diferentes analisis sobre cromatograf\'ias de suelo. 
Las \enquote{Cromatograf\'ias en Filtro Redondo de Pfeiffer} \cite{folla}. 
Este \cite{croma}.

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[env=bibliography]
\end{document}
```