# How to use apostrophes and quotation marks in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

Firstly. in my reference, it supposes to be `'Composition'`, but it turns up to be

```
’Composition’
```

below:

```
title={NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies: towards Attali's 'Composition'}
```

[image]

Secondly, why the volume and number do not shown correctly. 
It supposes to be `In:NMEDIAC: Journal of New Media & Culture, 3.1` and not `In:NMEDIAC: Journal of New Media & Culture 3.1` (see comma after `Culture`).

```
@article{mcintosh1997rhythmic,
  title={NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies: towards Attali's 'Composition'},
  author={Dean, Roger T},
  journal={NMEDIAC: Journal of New Media \& Culture},
  year={2005},
  number={1},
  volume={3}
}
```

The full code:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{mcintosh1997rhythmic,
  title={NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies: towards Attali's 'Composition'},
  author={Dean, Roger T},
  journal={NMEDIAC: Journal of New Media \& Culture},
  year={2005},
  number={1},
  volume={3}
}


\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear, 
  backend=biber, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % \jobname to use the bib file created with filecontents
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}

\makeatother


\begin{document}

According to \citeauthor{mcintosh1997rhythmic}'s studies 
\autocite*{mcintosh1997rhythmic}, blablabla 

\verb|\mycite|: \mycite{mcintosh1997rhythmic} ->        McIntosh et al. (1990) 

\verb|\textcite|: \textcite{mcintosh1997rhythmic}   ->        McIntosh et al. (1997) 

\verb|\parencite|: \parencite{mcintosh1997rhythmic}  ->        (McIntosh et al., 1997) 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean about “supposed to be ABC”.

Comment: I editted the post. It means the '

Comment: You want to change how the quotation marks and the possessive apostrophe are set?

Comment: For your quote marks you should use: `title={NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies: towards Attali's \mkbibquote{Composition}}`

Comment: @LokiRagnarok, yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `\mkbibquote{…}` in your title to ensure you get context sensitive quotes that alternate between ‘’ and “”.

As an aside, the standard way of writing left single and double quotes in LaTeX is to use a single and double backtick respectively. And the way to write right single and double quotes is the use a single and double straight quote respectively. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531/what-is-the-best-way-to-use-quotation-mark-glyphs).

You can redefine the `volume+number+eid` bibmacro to ensure that there is a comma before it.

## MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{mcintosh1997rhythmic,
  title={NoiseSpeech, a noise of living bodies: towards Attali's \mkbibquote{Composition}},
  author={Dean, Roger T},
  journal={NMEDIAC: Journal of New Media \& Culture},
  year={2005},
  number={1},
  volume={3}
}


\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[british]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[%
  style=authoryear, 
  backend=biber, 
  maxcitenames=2,
  giveninits
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} % \jobname to use the bib file created with filecontents
\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\renewcommand*{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\newcommand{\mycite}[1]{\citeauthor{#1}'s \citeyear{#1}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\begin{document}

According to \citeauthor{mcintosh1997rhythmic}'s studies 
\autocite*{mcintosh1997rhythmic}, blablabla 

\verb|\mycite|: \mycite{mcintosh1997rhythmic} ->        McIntosh et al. (1990) 

\verb|\textcite|: \textcite{mcintosh1997rhythmic}   ->        McIntosh et al. (1997) 

\verb|\parencite|: \parencite{mcintosh1997rhythmic}  ->        (McIntosh et al., 1997) 

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: thanks. How do you get this `\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}` from?

Comment: @aan, have a look through `standard.bbx`. Look for the `article` driver. You will see that it calls the `journal+issuetitle` macro. Look down lower in the file for the definition of `journal+issuetitle` and you will see it calls `volume+number+eid`. Notice that a space is inserted before the volume in the `journal+issuetitle` macro. Look down a little lower and find the `volume+number+eid` macro and you can see that we can insert a comma before the macro. `biblatex` tracks punctuation so only the most recently inserted punctuation set with `\setunit` is actually inserted.

Comment: thanks. Is this link http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-phys/phys.bbx correct? I googled `standard.bbx`, it ended up `standard bbc`

Comment: @aan No, this file: http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/latex/bbx/standard.bbx. You can find it on your own computer by running `kpsewhich standard.bbx` in a console.